# Printing Coordinates to a csv File with Data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, coordinates, export-to-csv

I need to extract coordinates with associated data to a .csv file.

I have a 4x4 matrix written as a list (network1) as well as corresponding values for each index (q_val). My goal is to identify the coordinates where a 1 occurs within network1, and export these coordinates along with the corresponding q_val to a .csv file.

Please see the current code below:

```
network1 = [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]
q_val = [50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550,600,650,700,750,800]

data = np.array(network1)
shape = (4,4)
network2 = data.reshape(shape)
print(network2)

coordinates = np.where(network2 == 1)
print(coordinates)

listOfCoordinates= list(zip(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]))

for coords in listOfCoordinates:      
    print(coords)
```

My Python output from this process looks correct and is as follows:

```
[[0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1]]

(array([0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int64), array([1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3], dtype=int64))

(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 2)
(3, 3)
```

It would be great to get some assistance to complete the following additional steps:

1. Shift the indices by +1 [i.e. the results should be (1,2), (2,3), (3,3), (3,4), (4,3), (4,4)].
2. Print these to a .csv file without the brackets and commas, delimited by spaces only. This should look like the photo below.
3. Ideally, I would also like it to print with the q_val in the header and the ; below the results.

[image: Ideal output]

I greatly appreciate any help - I'm sure there are more efficient methods of completing this process as well, so I am more than happy to take on board any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should satisfy your requirements:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

network1 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
q_val = [50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800]

network1_matrix = np.array(network1).reshape(4, 4)
q_val_matrix = np.array(q_val).reshape(4, 4)


coordinates = np.transpose(np.where(network1_matrix == 1))

filtered_values = [q_val_matrix[tuple(coordinate)] for coordinate in coordinates]

# Create the DataFrame and add 1 to each index
result_df = pd.DataFrame({'1': coordinates[:, 0] + 1, '2': coordinates[:, 1] + 1, '3': filtered_values})
# Add ';' in the end of the DataFrame
result_df = result_df.append({'1': ';', '2': '', '3': ''}, ignore_index=True)
# Add 'q_val' as header
result_df.columns = ['q_val', '', '']
# Export the DataFrame as csv file
result_df.to_csv('result.csv', sep=' ', index=False)
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly - fantastic, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code I have added/changed a few lines to your original code which I have commented:

```
import csv # import cvs

network1 = [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]
q_val = [50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550,600,650,700,750,800]


data = np.array(network1)
shape = (4,4)
network2 = data.reshape(shape)
print( network2)

coordinates = np.where(network2 == 1) 

# select the needed q_val 
q_val_selected = [q_val[i] for i,v in enumerate(network1) if network1[i]==1] # select the needed q_val 

print(coordinates)

# add "+1"s and the selected q_vals
listOfCoordinates= list(zip(coordinates[0] + 1, coordinates[1] + 1, q_val_selected)) 


for coords in listOfCoordinates:      
    print(coords)

# add a header and semicolon
listOfCoordinates = [("c1", "c2", "q_val")] + listOfCoordinates + [(";")]
    
# wrte to a csv file
with open('some.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=' ')
    writer.writerows(listOfCoordinates)
```

As you can see I have added two more labels in the header. Hope that's okay

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting this together! It also seems to work as intended - I appreciate the help.